# comparing the two arrays of objects is not working using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to compare to arrays of objects using angularjs. I have tried using angular.equals and no luck. I even assigned them to a variable to compare(initially they weren't) and it still does not detect them. I want to see if the arrays match. if they do--alert and/or reflect true in the {{equals}}

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function MyCtrl($scope) {

            $scope.thePath = {};
            $scope.thePath2 = {};


            $scope.clickme = function(val) {
                if (val in $scope.thePath) {
                    alert("already present");
                    console.log($scope.thePath);
                    return
                }

                $scope.thePath[val] = 1;



            }

            $scope.clickme2 = function(val) {
                if (val in $scope.thePath2) {
                    alert("already present");
                    console.log($scope.thePath2);
                    return
                }

                $scope.thePath2[val] = 1;



            }
            var obj1 = $scope.thePath;
            var obj2 = $scope.thePath2;
            //$scope.thepath vs $scope.thepath2
            $scope.thePath = obj1;
            $scope.thePath2 = obj2;
            $scope.equals = angular.equals(obj1, obj2);

            $scope.doubleCheck = function() {
                alert(obj1, obj2);

            }
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <p>Section A</p>
        <button id="uno" ng-click="clickme('Step A')">Path A</button><br>
        <button id="dos" ng-click="clickme('Step B')">Path B</button><br>
        <button is="cuatro" ng-click="clickme('Step C')">Path C</button><br>
        <button id="cinco" ng-click="clickme('Step D')">Path D</button><br>
        <button id="sieta" ng-click="clickme('Step E')">Path E</button> {{thePath}}


        <p>Section B</p>
        <button id="uno" ng-click="clickme2('Step A')">Path A</button><br>
        <button id="dos" ng-click="clickme2('Step B')">Path B</button><br>
        <button is="cuatro" ng-click="clickme2('Step C')">Path C</button><br>
        <button id="cinco" ng-click="clickme2('Step D')">Path D</button><br>
        <button id="sieta" ng-click="clickme2('Step E')">Path E</button> {{thePath2}}
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <p>Do these match?</p><button ng-click="doubleCheck()">Check</button> {{equals}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you trying to compare array or objects?? cause i see object instead of array.

Comment: this seems to working fine, however, you have a closing div after you last button that should not be there (or placed after your button actually). Your check will not work because it is not within your controller. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ojzdxpt1/24/

Comment: also, why are you using such an old version of angular?

Comment: yes it was arrays-sorry

Comment: @Ronnie i have not learned angular 2+ seems quite challenging

Comment: i mainly want to check if the order matches- not the content. Right now i get a true even if it appears out of order, but same content.

Comment: @Vzupo I meant why not angular 1.6? You are using 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

`angular.equals()` wont compare the order of the keys in the object. What you could do is `JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)`

Comment: when i apply this, it always remain true?

Comment: still isnt accurate

Comment: Please elaborate. You wanted to compare two array, but really you meant objects. You then said you wanted to compare them, including their order, which my solution solves. Click A then B. Click A then B and then check. Will result in TRUE. Click B then A. Click A then B and then click check. Will result in FALSE. Make sure you aren't looking at the first console.log()